# How to get the percentage of Selenium test case execution

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, automation, report, tracking

How to get the percentage of Selenium test case execution, also is there a way to show the real time Passed/Failed test case in the html report. Requirement is to get the percentage completed during the test case execution.

In need of your help friends.. Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

Hoping that you will use TestNG for running selenium scripts, use TestListenerAdapter(http://testng.org/javadocs/org/testng/TestListenerAdapter.html) to get the pass/fail count of the suite during the run and manipulate accordingly.